# What does the f appended in front mean?

Tags: c++

```
DetectorConstruction::DetectorConstruction()
:G4VUserDetectorConstruction(),
**fPBox(0), fLBox(0), fMaterial(0), fDetectorMessenger(0)**
{
  fBoxSize = 10*m;
  DefineMaterials();
  SetMaterial("Molybdenum98");  
  fDetectorMessenger = new DetectorMessenger(this);
}
```

What does the **f** mean in front of the functions? I am new to C++

Comment: It's just somebody's (not mine) idea of a good naming convention.  You can name these things anything you like.

Comment: Such things (as these prefixes) exist in many project's 'coding standard' or project style guides.  For example, in the Google Style Guide, you will find many sections addressing various Naming ideas.  My guess is that 'f' probably has no meaning.

Comment: It is possible that the author intended the 'f' prefix to distinguish these data attributes from similarly named attributes of other classes.  Perhaps somewhat analogous to a single letter namespace.  Have you ever noticed how many open, close, read, write exist in other languages.  Sometimes a single letter prefix can suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the author likes to put f as the first character of certain names.

Names can be almost any word-like collection of letters you like.

Comment: The more descriptive the better. Name things right and the code comments itself, for the most part.